# Escape special character at text

Tags: perl

I am reading a xml file, and I add some additional text, but I can't get exact text because some special characters automatically converted.

I try this:

```xml
<book>
  <book-meta>
    <book-id pub-id-type="doi">1545</book-id>
    <book-title>Regenerating <?tex?> the Curriculum</book-title>
  </book-meta>
</book>
```

Script:

```perl
use strict;

use XML::Twig;

open(my $out, '>', 'Output.xml') or die "can't Create stroy file $!\n";

my $story_file = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'book-id'       => sub { $_->set_text('<?sample?>') },
        keep_atts_order => 1,
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
);

$story_file->parsefile('sample.xml');
$story_file->print($out);
```

Output:

```xml
<book>
  <book-meta>
    <book-id pub-id-type="doi">&lt;?sample?></book-id>
      <book-title>Regenerating <?tex?> the Curriculum</book-title>
  </book-meta>
</book>
```

I would like output as:

```xml
<book>
      <book-meta>
        <book-id pub-id-type="doi"><?sample?></book-id>
          <book-title>Regenerating <?tex?> the Curriculum</book-title>
      </book-meta>
    </book>
```

How can I escape this type of character in XML twig. I tried the `set_asis` option, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Don't know if you absolutely want to use perl, but there's a python module someone wrote to convert xml to dicts. https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict

Comment: @Shelby.S: How would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XML::Twig` is correctly inserting the string `<?sample?>` for you as you are asking for a PCDATA node to be added and `<` must be replaced with `&lt;` in such a node. However what you want is a *processing instruction* node.

The easiest way to insert such a node using `XML::Twig` is using the `set_inner_xml` method, which will parse an XML tree fragment from a string and insert it as the contents of the current node.

If you replace

```perl
$_->set_text('<?sample?>')
```

with

```perl
$_->set_inner_xml('<?sample?>')
```

then your code should do what you want. The output I get is

```xml
<book>
  <book-meta>
    <book-id pub-id-type="doi"><?sample?></book-id>
    <book-title>Regenerating <?tex?> the Curriculum</book-title>
  </book-meta>
</book>
```

Comment: thank to all, it work well set_inner_xml options, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`<? ..... ?>` is not (part of)  text but a processing instruction. When you add it you your XML with `set_text` however it is processed as text, hence the `&lt;`.

I'm not familiar with `XML::Twig` myself, but I think you should check for the possibility to add a processing instruction instead of text.

Comment: I gave for sample this <?sample?> but < symbols as $lt automatically converted #PCDATA in xml twig, how can I escape here.